# Autofill histogram legend in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot, histogram

I have a file formatted like this :

```
"GTX 1080" 1700.0 1700.0
"Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4790 CPU @ 3.60GHz" 17.0 17.0
```

And I want to set the legend of an histogram in `gnuplot` with the first element of each line in that file.

When done manually it looks like this :

```
set xtics ("GTX 1080" 0, "Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4790 CPU @ 3.60GHz" 1)
```

But it needs to be done dynamically as I don't know the content of this file in advance.

**EDIT** : those lines :

```
plot DATA_SRC.'global.output' using 2:xticlabel(1) with hist title "  A" linecolor rgb "#66ccff", \
     DATA_SRC.'global.output' using 3:xticlabel(1) with hist title "  B" lt 1 lc rgb "#ee0000"
```

produces this error :

```
"GTX 1080" 1700.0 1700.0
^
"global.output", line 1: invalid command
```

**RE-EDIT** : this solution works in fact.

Comment: Use `plot 'file.dat' using 2:xticlabel(1)`, see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/17159569/2604213

Comment: The error returned is :
    `"GTX 1080" 1700.0 1700.0`
    `^`
    `"global.output", line 1: invalid command`

Comment: Then please edit your question to give us a full but minimal script which shows this error.

Comment: Question edited with the error message.

Comment: Pasting those two lines into the gnuplot prompt works fine for me, tested it with versions 4.6.6 and 5.0.

Comment: I wasn't reading the proper generated file, it works very well indeed thanks for your help !